# If $\{1^5,2^5,\ldots, (nm)^5\}$ is a complete residue system mod $nm$, prove $\{1^5,2^5,\ldots,n^5\}$ is a complete residue system mod $n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $n,m\ge 2$ be coprime positive integers. Prove that if $\{1^5,2^5,\ldots, (nm)^5\}$ is a complete residue system mod $nm$, then $\{1^5,2^5,\ldots,n^5\}$ is a complete residue system mod $n$.

This is equivalent to proving $$\left(a^5\equiv b^5\pmod{nm}\implies a\equiv b\pmod{nm}\right)$$

$$\implies \left(a^5\equiv b^5\pmod{n}\implies a\equiv b\pmod{n}\right)$$

Found in [AoPS](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t177f6h1084682_complete_residue_system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove given given $c\in\mathbb Z$ there is a solution to $a^5\equiv c\bmod p$ with $a\in \{1,2,3\dots p\}$. But we know there is a solution $a'\in\{1,2,3\dots pq\}$ to $(a')^5\equiv c\bmod pq$,since $a'$ is a solution $\bmod pq$ in particular it is a solution $\bmod p$. And so $(a')^5\equiv c\bmod p$. If we take $a$ so that $a\in \{1,2,3\dots p\}$ and $a\equiv a'\bmod p$ we will also have $a^5\equiv c\bmod p$. So we have found a solution to $a^5\equiv b\bmod p$ with $a\in\{1,2,3\dots p\}$ as desired.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteResidueSystem.html) disagree with your definition of a complete residue system.

Comment: Nope. Its the same. You want every congruence class to have a representative of the form b^5

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear $p,q$ are not prime. Also, your definition says that every _coprime_ class is of the form $b^5$, but not those classes non-coprime with the modulus.

Comment: Oh ok, let me edit my solution.

Comment: I edited the answer, please give me your feedback